# Paginator knp component awful performance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, database-performance

I follow this tutorial https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-relations/pagination

Because I need a way to paginate easily query results.

But I'm surprised by how long it is to do a simple count query.

This is the code

```
$pagination = $paginator->paginate($manager->getRepository(
App::getProductClassForGroup($selected_group_code))->findAllWithCurrentUserOptions($user->getId()),
$selected_page_number,
$product_per_page,
array('distinct' => false));
```

I have add in fourth parameter a `array('distinct' => false)` because I use foreign key as a primary key (see [this github issue](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/issues/106#issuecomment-29132150))

The query builder is the following one :

```
$queryBuilder->addSelect('prod');
$queryBuilder->innerJoin($this->_alias . '.product', 'prod');
$queryBuilder->addSelect('users_bookmarks');
$queryBuilder->leftJoin('prod.users_bookmarks', 'users_bookmarks', Join::WITH, 'users_bookmarks.id = :current_user_id');
$queryBuilder->setParameter('current_user_id', $current_user_id);
```

It is a verry simple query without even any `where` clause or anything.

And now this is the query being generated by `knp pagniator service` :

```
102.11 ms   
SELECT count(p0_.no_product_w2) AS sclr_0 FROM product_nat p0_ INNER JOIN product p1_ ON 
p0_.no_product_w2 = p1_.no_product LEFT JOIN users_bookmark_products u3_ ON
p1_.no_product = u3_.product_no LEFT JOIN User u2_ ON u2_.id = u3_.user_id AND (u2_.id = ?)
Parameters:
[▼
  1
]
```

This is EXPLAIN for the previous query :

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT count(p0_.no_product_w2) AS sclr_0 FROM product_nat p0_ INNER JOIN product
 p1_ ON p0_.no_product_w2 = p1_.no_product LEFT JOIN users_bookmark_products u3_
 ON p1_.no_product = u3_.product_no LEFT JOIN User u2_ ON u2_.id = u3_.user_id 
AND (u2_.id = 1)
_________________________
# id    select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  p0_     index   PRIMARY PRIMARY 36      24567   100.00  Using index
1   SIMPLE  p1_     eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 36  test.p0_.no_product_w2  1   100.00  Using index
1   SIMPLE  u3_     ref IDX_A4705D7D9D172915    IDX_A4705D7D9D172915    36  test.p0_.no_product_w2  1   100.00  Using index
1   SIMPLE  u2_     const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   const   1   100.00  Using where; Using index
```

The query generated by paginator take **102** ms !!!?

What am I doing wrong, why is that taking so much time ?

Is it just normal for a count query to take this much time ? I can't believe it.
How does other website are doing to manage pagination ?

What is the best practice to paginate.

I have try to do a count by myself for paginate, and I achieve to do this :

```
#Controller:index
$count_all_row = $manager->getRepository(App::getProductClassForGroup($selected_group_code))->countAll()
```

```
#Repository
/**
     * Count all rows
     * @param QueryBuilder|null $queryBuilder If no queryBuilder is provided, a new queryBuilder object is created
     * @return int|null Number of rows
     * @throws NoResultException
     * @throws NonUniqueResultException
     */
    public function countAll(?QueryBuilder $queryBuilder = null): ?int
    {
        $queryBuilder ??= $this->createQueryBuilder($this->_alias, ($this->_id) ? $this->_alias . '.' . $this->_id : null);
        return $queryBuilder->select('COUNT(1)')->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();;
    }
```

And it work in ~5.67ms which is much better.

```
5.67 ms 
SELECT COUNT(1) AS sclr_0 FROM product_nat p0_
```

My query builder is pretty simple because I just need to get how many rows did my table contains.
But now if I need to add other parameter like search product by title, or get product with price greater than 50$... I'll need to modify the `countAll()` function and the function to find all the result in my repository...

It doesn't seams a good practice to modify each time the function which just count the scalar results and the function which get the data results...